# Does anyone know where is the definition of "write_scr_el3" function in the arm-trusted-firmware repo?

Tags: c, linux, arm

In the arm-trusted-firmware repo, I can't find where the function "write_scr_el3" is defined, I guess this function is defined in a binary file somewhere, if you know, please let me know, I'd appreciate it. Thanks a lot.
for example:

```
void bl1_arch_setup(void)
{
    /* Set the next EL to be AArch64 */
    write_scr_el3(read_scr_el3() | SCR_RW_BIT);
}
```

Searched for all the files about write_scr_el3 in the arm-trusted-firmware repo, but I didn't search for a definition.

Comment: Would be better to add a link to the firmware repo so we know what this refers to. Other than that it's good to go.

Comment: Commonly when a search fails for an explicit word like 'write_scr_el3', you can reduce the search phrase to a substring like 'scr_el3'.  I have done this dozens of times to determine that some tool/process adds warts to identifiers.  The ultimate root of the structure is that the single ARM 'mrc/mcr'  and AARCH64 'msr' can be inlined to avoid function call overhead.  As there is no standard 'C' for this, the use is localized as it will differ depending on the tools, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`write_scr_el3` is either a macro or an inline function depending upon whether we're using `aarch32` or `aarch64`

---

In `include/arch/aarch32/arch_helpers.h`

`write_scr_el3` is defined as a macro that calls an `inline` function that is generated by a macro:

```
#define read_scr_el3()      read_scr()
#define write_scr_el3(_v)   write_scr(_v)

DEFINE_COPROCR_RW_FUNCS(scr, SCR)
```

---

In `include/arch/aarch64/arch_helpers.h`

`write_scr_el3` is defined as an `inline` function *by* a macro:

```
DEFINE_SYSREG_RW_FUNCS(scr_el3)

#define read_scr()              read_scr_el3()
#define write_scr(_v)           write_scr_el3(_v)
```

Comment: Right, it is generated by a macro, really thanks!